# Is it possible to create a regular expression for; landing page contains 'test=EMC' and ends with placement_id=

Tags: regex, google-analytics, analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-filters

Is it possible to create a regular expression for; landing page contains 'test=EMC' and ends with placement_id=

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

```
test=EMC.*placement_id=$
```

Does your placement_id parameter have a numeric value? In which case it would be

```
test=EMC.*placement_id=[0-9]+$
```